# AngularJS 1 или AngularJS 2

Tags: angularjs

Собираюсь изучать AngularJS для разработки на WEB.

Стоит ли изучать первую версию, или сразу же лучше учить вторую? Т.е. другими словами, вторая версия ничем не уступает первой, в плане разработки для WEB?

Comment: вторая версия - альфа.

Answer (score 1):

вторая версия официально не вышла. никто ее в продакшн не использует. доков по ней - минимум. рекомендую заниматься сейчас заниматься изучением исключительно первой версии. это позволит Вам понять общие концепции и особенности использования фреймворка и , после выхода сабжа, с минимальными потерями времени перейти на angularjs 2.0

Comment: на самом деле вторая версия так сильно отличается от первой, что изучение первой не особо-то и поможет

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо. А приблизительная дата выхода стабильного релиза второй версии не известна?

Comment: @Александр, на сколько мне известно - ничего не известно :-) можете у разработчиков уточнить

Comment: @Александр, https://github.com/angular/angular/milestones - судя по этому - первая версия беты только на половину готова

Answer (score 0):

Тоже такой вопрос вставал. `AngularJS 2.0` еще официально не вышел, инфраструктуры как таковой нет. Можно копаться, но больше для личного интереса, а не рабочего. Многое может поменяться в релизе.

Наткнулся еще на пару статей, в которых говорилось, что разработчики будут  решать проблему миграции ... как? - слабо представляю.

Для себя принял решение осваивать и работать с `AngularJS 1.4`. Выкатят 2.0 - будем посмотреть.

Лишние навыки еще никому вреда не приносили ...